# what does struct sched_domain stands for in include/linux/sched.h (scheduling domains in kernel)

Tags: c, kernel, intel, scheduler, processor

I am trying to understand how load balancer works on multiprocessor system in Linux kernel,

Linux scheduler basically uses runques to store the tasks which it has to run next,
now taking situation of a multiprocessor system
the way load_balancer() is implemented  an explanation as given in Robert Loves book Linux Kernel Development 2nd edition is following

> First, load_balance() calls find_busiest_queue() to determine the
>   busiest runqueue. In other words, this is the runqueue with the
>   greatest number of processes in it. If there is no runqueue that has
>   25% or more processes than the current, find_busiest_queue() returns
>   NULL and load_balance() returns. Otherwise, the busiest runqueue is
>   returned.
>
> Second, load_balance() decides which priority array on the busiest
>   runqueue it wants to pull from. The expired array is preferred because
>   those tasks have not run in a relatively long time, thus are most
>   likely not in the processor's cache (that is, they are not cache hot).
>   If the expired priority array is empty, the active one is the only
>   choice.
>
> Next, load_balance() finds the highest priority (smallest value) list
>   that has tasks, because it is more important to fairly distribute high
>   priority tasks than lower priority ones.
>
> Each task of the given priority is analyzed, to find a task that is
>   not running, not prevented to migrate via processor affinity, and not
>   cache hot. If the task meets this criteria, pull_task() is called to
>   pull the task from the busiest runqueue to the current runqueue.
>
> As long as the runqueues remain imbalanced, the previous two steps are
>   repeated and more tasks are pulled from the busiest runqueue to the
>   current. Finally, when the imbalance is resolved, the current runqueue
>   is unlocked and load_balance()returns.

the code is following

```
static int load_balance(int this_cpu, runqueue_t *this_rq,
                        struct sched_domain *sd, enum idle_type idle)
{
        struct sched_group *group;
        runqueue_t *busiest;
        unsigned long imbalance;
        int nr_moved;

        spin_lock(&this_rq->lock);

        group = find_busiest_group(sd, this_cpu, &imbalance, idle);
        if (!group)
                goto out_balanced;

        busiest = find_busiest_queue(group);
        if (!busiest)
                goto out_balanced;

        nr_moved = 0;
        if (busiest->nr_running > 1) {
                double_lock_balance(this_rq, busiest);
                nr_moved = move_tasks(this_rq, this_cpu, busiest,
                                      imbalance, sd, idle);
                spin_unlock(&busiest->lock);
        }
        spin_unlock(&this_rq->lock);

        if (!nr_moved) {
                sd->nr_balance_failed++;

                if (unlikely(sd->nr_balance_failed > sd->cache_nice_tries+2)) {
                        int wake = 0;

                        spin_lock(&busiest->lock);
                        if (!busiest->active_balance) {
                                busiest->active_balance = 1;
                                busiest->push_cpu = this_cpu;
                                wake = 1;
                        }
                        spin_unlock(&busiest->lock);
                        if (wake)
                                wake_up_process(busiest->migration_thread);
                        sd->nr_balance_failed = sd->cache_nice_tries;
                }
        } else
                sd->nr_balance_failed = 0;

        sd->balance_interval = sd->min_interval;

        return nr_moved;

out_balanced:
        spin_unlock(&this_rq->lock);

        if (sd->balance_interval < sd->max_interval)
                sd->balance_interval *= 2;

        return 0; 
}
```

What I am not clear with is a structure in above code struct sched_domain *sd
this structure I checked is defined in 
include/linux/sched.h as follows 
http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.7.1/include/linux/sched.h#L895
it is a big structure so I have just given a link for simplicity.
What I want to know is what is the use of struct sched_domain in above code?

Why is this used when load_balancer() is called what does this struct stands for?

a bit of things are given here probably
http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-domains.txt
why does a CPU needs scheduling domains? What do these domains stand for?

Answer (score 15):

Scheduling domains and scheduler groups/cpu groups help to ease the
process of scheduling tasks like:

1. load balancing tasks across cpus.
2. choosing a cpu for a new task to run on.
3. choosing a cpu for a sleeping task to run when it wakes up.

It has a two fold advantage:

1. It organises the cpus in the system very well into groups and hierarchies.
2. It organises the cpus in such a way that it is useful.All cpus which
   share an l2 cache belong to one domain.All cpus which share an l3 cache
   belong to a higher level domain,which encompasses all the domains which
   share the l2 cache.

The advantages that you see with a tree like data structure are similar
here to the advantages of scheduler domains and groups.

Refer to following diagram

```
     _________sd1________
    /                    \
    ----------------------
         l3 cache
    ----------------------
    ---------   ----------
    l2 cache    l2 cache
    ---------   ----------
    cpu0 cpu1   cpu2 cpu3
    \_______/   \________/
      sd0          sd0

 ________sd1_________
/                    \
----------------------
      l3 cache
----------------------
---------   ----------
l2 cache    l2 cache
---------   ----------
cpu4 cpu5   cpu6 cpu7
\_______/   \________/
  sd0          sd0
```

What you see above is a scheduler domain hierarchy.sd1 encompasses sd0s
which happen to be scheduler groups of sd1.Every cpu has a scheduler
domain hierarchy associated with it.For eg.
cpu0->sd=sd0; sd0->parent=sd1.This way through a linked list we can
iterate through all the scheduler domains to which a cpu belongs to.

How does this help?

1.load balancing: Say cpu0 is idle and is ready to pull tasks upon
itself to relieve any other burdened cpu.In the above approach,it first
checks if the other cpus that belong to the first level sched domain
,needs to be relieved of load.Here, cpu1.If so it takes on tasks from
cpu1,else it goes to the higher level domain sd1.If it chooses to
migrate task from cpu1 it is the best thing,because the cache contents
can be utilized;shared cache.no need to fetch from memory again.This is
the first advantage:sched domains are formed based upon the advantages
that hardware has to provide.

If it goes to sd1,then it probes sd1's 'groups',both the sd0s.Here is
the next advantage.It needs information about the sched group alone and
will not bother about the individual cpus in it.it checks if
load(sd0[cpu2,cpu3]) > load(sd0[cpu0,cpu1])
Only if this is true does it go on to see if cpu2/3 is more loaded.If
there were no scheduler domain or groups,we would have to see the states
of cpu2 and cpu3 in two iterations instead of 1 iteration like we are
doing now.

Now scale this problem and solution to 128 cpus! imagine what a mess it
would have been if there was nothing to tell you which cpu would be the
best to relieve load from,in the worst case you would have to iterate
through all the 128 cpus.

But with scheduler domain or groups,say you divide the 128 cpus into
groups of 16 cpus,you would have 8 groups.see which is the busiest,so
that would be 8 iterations,then you would know the busiest group,then
descend down.another 16 iterations.so worst case

8+16 = 24 iterations.And this decrease is only with one level of sched
domain. Imagine if you had more levels,you would make the number of
iterations even lower.

So in short the scheduler domains and groups are a 'divide and conquer
;but conquer as much as possible what is more useful' solution to
scheduling related stuff.

I posted in case some one in future might want to read it.